# Which browser can't use the header location redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, header, location

We use header('Location...') for redirect on lot of request. We have 4% of request, that don't do it.

Do you have any idea?

Our requests are from all countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Location header needs to be implemented by every browser.** It's a part of [HTTP/1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html), so if anything wants to call itself a "web browser" than it needs to implement Location header. So answering your question: every web browser can use `Location:`.

Still though there is something you need to consider:

First thing you need to remember is that the `header('Location` needs to use **absolute paths**, as relative URL might not be supported or behave incorrectly in different browsers (old IE had issues with that - according to RFC 2616 the location header needs to be absolute). So it might be worth checking if you always use absolute URLs in redirects.

Second thing is that your **tracking system** might not work correctly. If someone uses [do not track policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_not_track_header) or edits his [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) than your tracking system might be fooled into thinking that the redirect did not occur. While it still does, only your tracker won't see it happening.

And third and final thing are **[web crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)** which might ignore headers completely (they almost never do, but it might be one of these rare cases where someone has an amature spam bot trying to crawl through your site), or send incorrect responses.

I agree that 4% is oddly high, but it might happen even solely from a single, long attempt of crawl your website by some dodgy bot.

Hope it helps!